# SQLlite Algorithm to divide two table columns and output the number into a new table

Tags: algorithm, sqlite, pascal, lazarus

I'm new to SQL and have created a database within Lazarus and the language pascal. I am currently using SQLlite3. So far i have created a database that has the current assets and liabilities (integers) of a business, however i need to create an algorithm that would divide these two numbers and input the "ratio" division of these two numbers into a new table, any help would be appreciated.

many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sql below creates two Sqlite tables

> Companies with columns CompanyID, Assets and Liabilities
>
> CompanyAL with columns CompanyID and Ratio (of Liabilites to Assets)

It then populates the Companies table with a couple of rows, then uses an

```
insert into ... select ...
```

to insert the ratio of the Assets/Liabilities into the CompanyAL table.

Important:  In Sqlite, the "divide" symbol, `/`, gives an integer result by default and so would give the Ratio values 0 and 2.  To overcome that, you need to use an expression which multiplies the result by 1.0;  I've done that in the numerator and denomination for the expression to calculate the value in the Ratio column.

```
CREATE  TABLE "main"."Companies" ("CompanyID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  check(typeof("CompanyID") = 'integer') , "Assets" INTEGER check(typeof("Assets") = 'integer') , "Liabilities" INTEGER check(typeof("Liabilities") = 'integer') );

CREATE  TABLE "main"."CompanyAL" ("CompanyID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  check(typeof("CompanyID") = 'integer') , "Ratio" FLOAT);

insert into Companies(CompanyID, Assets, Liabilities) values(1, 100, 50);
insert into Companies(CompanyID, Assets, Liabilities) values(2, 50, 100);

insert into CompanyAL select CompanyID, (Liabilities  * 1.0 / Assets * 1.0) from Companies
```

Tested for Sqlite using the `Sqlite Manager`  add-in for Firefox.  Obviously in your Lazarus app, you would construct the necessary Sql in code and use a suitable db component to execute it against the database.